Can't see the attached images in Stack Exchange questions in Sweden
Since last week, I can not see the images attached to questions in any Stack Exchange site. I have tried accessing the same thread from different browsers and different devices. The issue is persistent in all cases.

Example from physics.stackexchange.com
Thread: Physical interpretation of density of states
My P.O.V Screenshot: https://freeimage.host/i/screenshot-from-2024-08-05-14-48-33.d5Z5GHl
RayID: 8afed28069c382be

Example from webapps.stackexchange.com
Thread: How to find the country/nation/province of a specific point when using google maps?
My P.O.V Screenshot: https://freeimage.host/i/screenshot-from-2024-08-01-16-52-36.dA77jZN
RayID: 8afed4597f2482be
RayID: 8afed46fba3e82be
RayID: 8afed47cd82b82be
RayID: 8afed4896b2682be


The same issue is there in other forums as well, when I click on the image link I get the follwoing error.
https://freeimage.host/i/screenshot-from-2024-08-05-14-49-20.d5ZYCYv
The issue is there since last week, I thought this was a temporary bug and will be fixed soon. However no fix has been issued so far. I belive this has to be some problem with the CDN server of stackexchange.
I'm browsing from Sweden without VPN. I observed the issue on an HP desktop computer running on Ubuntu 23. OS with Chrome, Brave, and Firefox browsers. The Issue is also observed in a Dell laptop running Windows OS with all the same browsers. (Both devices are connected to the same network)
Update: I can see the images on this thread (Realistically randomize Rubik's Cube). So this is not caused by a situation in which the ISP or the DNS server blocked the '.sstatic.net' server. If that were the case I would not see any images at all.
Update: While browsing the same threads from a mobile device with a different network, the images are visible. That is when I access these threads from my phone with mobile internet, I can see the images. However, when I connect my phone to the same network with WiFi, I have the same issue and the images are not visible.
Update (06/Aug/2024 9:55 CEST): Now I can see one image (https://i.sstatic.net/vj98pfo7.png)  in the second thread (webapps). Previously none of the images were visible.
Update (07/Aug/2024 10:52 CEST): The image that appeared in the previous update disappeared now. Everything else remained the same
Update (08/Aug/2024 12:32 CEST): The second image in the Physics thread is visible now, I added the RayID of the images that are not visible to the question.

Same issue. TL;DR: CloudFlare is buggy and serve images (or not) based on god-knows-what filters. The most sad part is that SE has almost no control over it.

@ShadowWizard I just checked that thread, the issue is quite similar. However, I Can see the images reported in that thread.

@PhysicsStudent once seen in other place, it magically appears in the place where you didn't see it before. Why? How? Only CloudFlare staff might have a real answer. That is also what makes it a very elusive and impossible to fix, on SE side.

Clearing cookies did not work for me

If your WiFi network is shared (ie, University Campus, Employer office, Apartment building public Wifi), it's more likely that your IP is being blocked for suspicion of malicious traffic. Though, it's weird that CloudFlare loads the page successfully, but fails on the images. Seems like something is misconfigured with CDN/DDoS protection to allow that to happen.

@testing-for-ya, Hi as explained in the last two updates (1) Trying from mobile internet, all the images listed here are visible (2) Trying again results in one image being visible.

I'm the OP from the other question and even though, as edited into it, I can now see the images reported there I can now see the images in the Realistically randomize Rubik's Cube thread, I just checked and I still can't see the images on physics and webapps or other threads on Blender. [Edit: seems fixed as of today - 6 August '24] I tried opening the physics page in Chrome (normally I use Firefox) and still the same problem. Tried clearing (all time) cookies 3 times, still nothing.
So, to test further, I launched Cloudflare WARP, and refreshed the physics page in Chrome once again, and now the images appeared! Then I disabled the WARP, refreshed the physics page in Firefox, and surprisingly, the images appeared there as well.
Even more surprisingly, when I decided to open the webapp page in Firefox, which I didn't open in Chrome and/or when using WARP, and then I see this:



So one out of four images has loaded properly...

Same for me! I can see this image now, while the other images are still not loaded.

@PhysicsStudent perhaps there's a causation here: because I linked this particular thread, images in it work. Was it some kind of cloudflare or other employee that fixed this particular case, or was it some automatic magic whereas just because additional activity in the thread (and a cross-site one), the images were maybe e.g. moved to a different cache server? I have very little knowledge about networking so those are layman's guesses. Oh and I can see all the images today (all sites)

Update, the image that appeared disappeared again. @MarkusVonBroady

@testing-for-ya Updated the question with RayID of the images that are not loaded
